# Relation of order of a permutation with its sign

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group with order $2m$ where $m$ is odd. Consider the left action $\lambda_g:G\to G$.

> It appears that if $g$ has odd order iff $\lambda_g$ has odd order iff $\lambda_g$ is an even permutation.

Is this true and can we generalize this observation?

Comment: Can you clarify what sort of relation you suspect?  For example, in $S_6$ the elements $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5)$ and $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)(5\ 6)$ are both even permutations, but the first has order $5$ and the second has order $4$.  So I'm not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: If $\sigma=c_{1} \ldots c_{p}$ is the decomposition of the permutation $\sigma$ into a product of *disjoint* cycles ($c_{i}$ being a cycle of length $k_{i}$), then :

$$ \varepsilon(\sigma) = \varepsilon(c_{1}) \ldots \varepsilon(c_{p}) = (-1)^{\big(\sum k_{i} \big) - p} $$

And one can prove that, if $\sigma=c_{1} \ldots c_{p}$, then the order of $\sigma$ in $S_{n}$ is equal to $\mathrm{lcm}(k_{1},\ldots,k_{p})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The orbits of $\lambda_g$ are exactly the right cosets $\langle g\rangle/G$.

On each orbit, $\lambda_g$ is cyclic of odd length thus has even sign. Also $\lambda_g$ decomposes into $|\langle g\rangle/G|$ number of disjoint cycles. Therefore the sign of $\lambda_g$ is the sum of signs of the disjoint cycles, which is even.

For the converse, one can use proof by contradiction. If $g$ has even order, then $\lambda_g$ has odd sign on each orbit. There are $|\langle g\rangle /G|$ number of cycles, which is odd by assumption that $|G| = 2m$. Therefore the sign of $\lambda_g$ on $G$ is an odd sum of odd integers, which is odd. Contradiction.